# Building example app fails in Appcelerator

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I created a new project (Default Alloy Mobile App) and trying to run it in 9.3 iPhone 6 simulator when it fails.

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   CompileC build/Intermediates/fdsafda.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/i386/WatchSessionModule.o Classes/WatchSessionModule.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

And if I open the project in Xcode it says that `/Users/me/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/Test/build/iphone/Classes/WatchSessionModule.h:10:9: 'WatchConnectivity/watchConnectivity.h' file not found`

I have the following installed

- Xcode 7.3.1 (build 7D1014)
- Command Line Tools 7.3.1.0.1.1461711523
- Ti SDK 5.2.2.GA
- APPC Studio 4.5
- APPC cli 5.2.2
- APPC ti -v 5.0.6
- Node.js Version 4.4.4

Comment: Could you try to reinstall the Titanium SDK (`appc ti sdk install 5.2.2.GA --force`) and clean your project (`appc ti clean`) and try again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, it's because i'm installing MacOSX in case sensitive partition, so to fix it just fix the case:

```
watchConnectivity.h -> WatchConnectivity.h
```